# Change SVG color in Vue

Tags: css, vue.js, svg

I have this static existing svg that I have difficulties changing the color.

```
<img class="icon-shop" src="@/assets/icon-shop.svg"/>


<style>
.icon-shop {
  width: 32px;
  fill: orange;
  stroke: orange;
}
</style>
```

I've found a solution using `filter` attribute but it shouldn't be this complicated.

```
filter: invert(35%) sepia(36%) saturate(7009%) hue-rotate(2deg)
    brightness(104%) contrast(88%);
```

Comment: You can't style svg like that, you need to display it inline to be able to target it with css.

Comment: you should be able to open the svg file on any text editor and you can edit it by changing the <path fill=" your color choice"> there are some instances that you will see some tags like circle, polygon etc. there you should be able to edit the color.

Answer (score 0):

Sample is this if you change the fill="YOUR COLOR" that should change. You can view any svg on any text editor and change from there.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="300.000000pt" height="300.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 300.000000 300.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<metadata>
Created by potrace 1.10, written by Peter Selinger 2001-2011
</metadata>
<g transform="translate(0.000000,300.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="red" stroke="none">
<path d="M212 2613 c-128 -45 -197 -230 -142 -376 26 -70 122 -200 188 -255
39 -33 219 -160 962 -678 41 -28 104 -67 140 -85 58 -30 74 -34 145 -34 74 0
85 3 150 39 39 21 165 104 280 185 116 81 341 239 502 350 217 151 310 221
361 275 108 114 152 208 153 328 1 119 -63 215 -171 253 -37 13 -209 15 -1284
14 -1087 0 -1246 -2 -1284 -16z"/>
<path d="M50 1228 c0 -745 -2 -723 72 -798 22 -23 58 -50 81 -61 40 -18 87
-19 1297 -19 l1255 0 50 24 c55 25 105 76 132 134 16 34 18 95 21 705 2 367 0
667 -3 667 -3 0 -34 -24 -69 -54 -36 -30 -106 -83 -158 -117 -160 -107 -596
-411 -753 -523 -304 -219 -447 -257 -656 -175 -88 36 -129 62 -546 355 -142
99 -337 234 -433 300 -96 65 -200 143 -232 173 l-58 53 0 -664z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```